# Is there a <C-w> for WORDs?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, word-processing

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> in Insert mode will delete the previous word. It is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in Windows, and <kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> in OS X, and really speeds up typing.

Vim has the separate concepts of `word` and `WORD` (see `:help word`). This is invaluable for text navigation: it is the difference between <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd>, and so on.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> operates on `word`. Is there a similar instruction for `WORD`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there is one built in, but you can map one yourself in your vimrc:

```
inoremap <c-b> <esc>vBda
```

Comment: I like this. It's an available, open mapping with a clear mnemonic.

Comment: I think `<esc>BdiWi` might be better. `vBda` doesn't seem to behave consistently (try inside, for example, `db:seed`).

Comment: When doing one of normal mode commands from insert mode, consider using `<C-o>` instead